# Why does a catch behave like a resolve?

Tags: javascript, promise

I can't wrap my head around why this code executes as:

1. "Could not reach server"
2. "Success: Data has been loaded"

Why does the `loadData().then()` gets called when nowhere ever seems to occur a resolve?

I realize I can "fix" the code by throwing the error in the first catch, so that the last/higher catch will see the error. But I'd like to know who or what is responsible for apparently resolving my code, causing to reach the .then() in this scenario.

Is not re-throwing the error in the first catch considered a resolve(), as this piece of code implies it to be?

Or what about the behavior of Promises am I missing here?

```
function doGoogleRequest(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        reject("Could not reach server.");
    });
}

function loadData(){
    return doGoogleRequest()
        .then(function(data){
            return data;
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.error(err);
        });
}

loadData()
  .then(function(){
    console.log("Success: Data has been loaded.");
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("Error: could not load data");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are catching the error, which indicates an *intent* to handle it. Since you don't "re-throw" it again, your code assumes that you handled it in the appropriate way and it's no longer an error.

This is the exact same behaviour as `try..catch`. If you `catch` an error and don't re-throw it, code below it (or calling code) continues to run.

If you remove the `catch` from your `loadData` Promise chain, it works as expected.

```js
function doGoogleRequest(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        reject("Could not reach server.");
    });
}

function loadData(){
    return doGoogleRequest()
        .then(function(data){
            return data;
        });
}

loadData()
  .then(function(){
    console.log("Success: Data has been loaded.");
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("Error: could not load data");
});
```

Comment: So just checking if I'm getting this right:
by catching the error as I did in my example (intending to handle it, and not re-throwing it), I'm basically telling my code that I have resolved the promise? 
The higher piece of code receives loadData() as a resolved promise, causing .then() to be called?

Comment: Yes but keep in mind that in the case you do handle the error in `catch`, you must return a result from your `catch`, which will then get picked up in the `then` of the promise chain it is part of. If you can't handle the error properly in your `catch` then you **must** `throw`, so that it triggers any chained `catch`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. I'm finally understanding it thanks to your really clear input!

Answer (score 0):

This is their natural behavior.
Why does it crucial? Because not every time having error means we should just stop there. The same way as `try ... catch ...` allows us to continue working instead of just halting completely.

Do you need to pass error one level upper? Just rethrow error or throw brand new one.

Once you have some workaround to handle an error without stopping everything - you are able doing that in `catch()` section.